# I can not update the value in the database Yii?

Tags: php, yii

I can not update the value in the database. Here's the code:

```
if($user = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$verification->username)))
{
    //  Generating 8 random symbols for new password
    $new_password = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 8)), 0, 8);

    //  Transfering password to MD5 hash with salt!
    $new_password = md5('salt'.$new_password);
    $user->password = $new_password;
    if($user->save())
{...
```

The debugger shows that the value and get it replaced (password), but when you save

> if($user->save())
>       {

Gives false and resets to the most recent line of code:

> $this->render('forget');

**Questions:**

1. How to find out what happened and why did not update the value?
2. How to find the error (error code, ...)?

Comment: Do a `if($user->save()) { [...] } else { var_dump($user-errors); }` and see if and what the validation errors are.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got an error and the answer "int (1)" what it means?

Comment: Sorry had a typo which I cannot correct anymore. Please do a `if($user->save()) { [...] } else { var_dump($user->errors); }`. You should get an array with error messages in response.

Comment: Great! I know the problem, validation - array ('password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'repeat_password')
In the database there is no field "repeat_password" but I'm registering it compare with the field "password".
Now I need to somehow insert it into the code. If I put $user->repeat_password = $new_password; an error occurs. 
How to send it to the "password"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your last comment, If you have no `repeat_password` field into your table, add it by hand in your model. (User model). (Actually there is no need to have this field in your table.)

```
public $repeat_password
```

Then, define rules for the field. (for example, required and so on...)

To get validation error you can do like below:

```
CVarDumper::dump($model->getErrors(),56789,true);
```